# Jenkins throws org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA

Tags: maven, jenkins, soapui, soap-client

I am running automated tests using SOAPUI. My tests run safe when running in SOAPUI but one test fails when running in Jenkins as maven project.

```
10:54:36,633 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [error: Unexpected element: CDATA], see error log for details
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3486)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:712)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:696)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:683)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject$Factory.parse(XmlObject.java:580)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.createXmlObject(XmlUtils.java:263)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.ResolverUtils.extractXPathPropertyValue(ResolverUtils.java:97)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.ResolverUtils.parseProperty(ResolverUtils.java:67)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.ResolverUtils.checkForExplicitReference(ResolverUtils.java:44)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.ModelItemPropertyResolver.getScopedProperty(ModelItemPropertyResolver.java:218)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.ModelItemPropertyResolver.resolveProperty(ModelItemPropertyResolver.java:51)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpander.expand(PropertyExpander.java:184)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpander.expandProperties(PropertyExpander.java:112)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext.expand(WsdlTestRunContext.java:157)
at com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunContext$expand.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:34)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:100)
at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion.assertScript(GroovyScriptAssertion.java:122)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion.internalAssertResponse(GroovyScriptAssertion.java:139)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlMessageAssertion.assertResponse(WsdlMessageAssertion.java:165)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequest.assertResponse(RestTestRequest.java:156)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequest.setResponse(RestTestRequest.java:141)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep.run(RestTestRequestStep.java:927)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:52)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:152)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:47)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 53; Unexpected element: CDATA
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3454)
```

I am trying to load a stored variable from project custom properties.

```
`context.expand( '${#TestCase#ControllerIds#$[1]}' )`
```

Could some one tell me a fix for this.

Comment: Looks you got it resolved for yourself as per http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Jenkins-throws-org-apache-xmlbeans-XmlException-error-Unexpected/m-p/109273#U109273

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem . actually not fixed but handled it in a different way.

```
def vUControllerIds = []
vUControllerIds = context.expand( '${#TestCase#VUControllerIds}' )
def vUControllerId = new GroovyShell().evaluate(vUControllerIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed by switching to soap ui pro maven plugin version 5.1.0 where that bug has been fixed. You will also need to add extra dependency in order to avoid class not found error:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
     <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.0</version>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>  
            <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>  
            <version>0.9.9-RC2</version>  
        </dependency>
 .......
 <plugin>
```