# SoapUITestCaseRunner class not found issue when doing maven build for soap UI project

Tags: maven, soapui

I was doing maven configuration for soapUI project using latest maven-soapui-pro plugin,however i was facing below error

```
*Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test (default) on project medtronicAcsSoapUI: Execution default of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test failed: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test: com/eviware/soapui/tools/SoapUITestCaseRunner*
```

These are the dependencies I was using.

```
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>

            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Could someone please help me.

Comment: Think you have to add the soapui-<version>.jar as a dependency to your project

Comment: I have tried by adding soap ui the jar.
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
      <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency> 



Still it throws same erorr

Answer (score 0):

With this pom.xml the execution is right,
[image]

I have updated the artifactId:

```
<artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

by

```
<artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

you need to have installation the soaupUI aplication and this pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.41594333</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui.mvn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <restEndpointUrl>http://server:port</restEndpointUrl>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>Completed-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    <testSuite>CreateCase</testSuite>
                    <outputFolder>target</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>
                    <projectProperties>
                        <value>QA_server=${restEndpointUrl}</value>
                    </projectProperties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,however I missed to post full pom file.
I have included all that.

Comment: you don´t included the pom file.Please could you review?

Comment: I really appreciate the help you have done.
however If I use "soapui-maven-plugin" project will execute, but I would be getting an error saying that "- Error performing transfer [access_token] - error: Unexpected element: CDATA" . hence to over come this error i have tried"<artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>"  as someone explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809532/jenkins-throws-org-apache-xmlbeans-xmlexception-error-unexpected-element-cdat).

by the way I was using soapUI property transfer step in the project.

Comment: and if you upgrade the version.5.1.2,
5.1.3,
5.2.0,
5.2.1,
5.3.0,

Comment: tried upgrading the versions also not worked,but 5.3.0 is not yet released right?

Comment: Could you write your system version  and configuration? I don´t understand because it is your problem.

Comment: I have soap ui 5.2.1 installed and maven 3.3.9

Comment: Do i need to point soap Ui somewhere to execute in maven? because tests are executed only if i add below dependency "<groupId>eviware</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>"

Comment: Please could you write the error, the screenshot and command mvn?

Comment: i am using "mvn test" as a command from the project directory.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.2.1:test (default) on project medtronicAcsSoapUI: Execution default of goal
com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.2.1:test failed: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.2.
1:test: com/eviware/soapui/tools/SoapUITestCaseRunner

Comment: I am not able to upload the image :(

Comment: Coudl you execute this command `mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:5.1.2:test -X`  and attach the log?

Comment: `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins | grep -i  "plexus-util" ` in my code has this: `[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.0.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-1.5.10.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
` this jar always is top version to 1.1.

Comment: I tried to build the same project in one of my friend workspace,there also I am facing same class not found issue. pls somebody help me here

Comment: Is there any archetype issue?